# About zooming in D3 radial tree

Tags: d3.js

Hi I am learning D3 and working on this cluster radial tree. I am stuck at the zooming and panning characteristics of the radial tree. When I am trying to zoom in, the tree goes to the (0,0) coordinate of the window and doesn't stay at the center of the window. I was wondering if anyone working on a similar project would like to shed some light on how to keep the tree at the center of the screen while zooming and panning. Thanks

Comment: This example might help: http://jsdatav.is/visuals.html?id=4a3b74228d9cb11eb486  It's discussed in detail in the book [Data Visualization with JavaScript](http://www.nostarch.com/datavisualization) The online version is the [last example](http://jsdatav.is/chap07.html)

Comment: Thanks Stephen for responding. I took a look at the link and it is indeed full of a lot of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a current zoom translate vector and specify the coordinates for it. For example with my project, I had to use, .translate([480,480]). This appears to be the vector that sets your plot on the path to zooming. Here is the snippet of code I used for calling the zoom:

```
d3.select("svg")
  .call(d3.behavior.zoom()
  .center([770,450])
  .scaleExtent([0.3,10])
  .translate([480,480]) //add this to your zoom call, but adjust coordinates
  .on("zoom",zoom))
```

Comment: As a side note, you should probably adjust the coordinates of .translate() to the coordinates of your root node.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing the idea. It worked. All this while, I was experimenting with .center([]) and other methods from the API. Thanks again.